# Being able to retrieve more information from the current logged on user session c#

Tags: c#, sql, session, authentication, information-retrieval

I have created a c# login which checks the username and password is correct from my SQL database, if the login credentials are correct it will create a session named "correct".

In the table named `Staff`(where the login information is coming from) I also have a `StaffTypeID` which is linked to another table named `staff types`. In my staff types there are Admin, supervisor etc.

I need to retrieve the the `StaffTypeID` from the current users session, upon doing this I will be able to give the current user the relevant access to  certain parts of the system. Is there a way that this is possible to do?

Here is my login code:

```
SqlConnection loginConnection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LabelsDressShopConnection"].ConnectionString);
loginConnection.Open();
string checkUser = "select count(*) from Staff where EmailAddress ='" + txtEmail.Text + "'";
SqlCommand compair = new SqlCommand(checkUser, loginConnection);
int tempVar = Convert.ToInt32(compair.ExecuteScalar().ToString());

loginConnection.Close();

if (tempVar == 1)
{
    loginConnection.Open();
    string checkUserPassword = "select Password from Staff where EmailAddress ='" + txtEmail.Text + "'"; ;

    SqlCommand passComm = new SqlCommand(checkUserPassword, loginConnection);
    string password = passComm.ExecuteScalar().ToString().Replace(" ","");

    if (password == txtPassword.Text) {
        Session["correct"] = txtEmail.Text;
        Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
    }
    else {
        Response.Write("Username or Password incorrect");
    }
}
else {
    Response.Write("Username or Password incorrect");
}
```

Comment: Do not trust any values from the browser i.e. the code is susceptible to SQL injection.

Comment: Switch from executescalar to executereader and add the stafftypeid to the password query.  See this post on how to use executereader https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/haa3afyz%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: @WorkSmarter thank you for your comment, I will defiantly take a look and try to re write my code :)